# Complete graph, $K^3$ and topological minors

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question concerning complete graphs.

In the Diestel's book, page 63, there is this statement:

Let $G$ be a graph.

As $G\neq K^4$, there is a $3-$connected graph $J\not\simeq G$ such that $G$ contains a $TJ$.

> > I really don't see why this is true. Here, $TJ$ is a topological minor of $J$.

Thank you.

Comment: I am a beginner in graph theory and many things are involved in one sentence: complete, isomorphism, minor, connectedness. I would need some help. Thank you.

Comment: There's some context we're missing here. I assume $G$ must be $3$-connected. What else do we know about $G$? Do you mean $K^3$ or $K_4$?

Comment: Could you give us more context? There are many different editions of Diestel's book and I can't find this statement in mine

Comment: thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your help. It is the fifth edition. By $K^4$ we mean a complete graph on 4 vertex.
Here is the context:http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/GrTh5_Ch3.pdf

I think I got the idea. 
Since $G$ is 3-connected and different from $K^4$, I took $K^5$ in blue in my picture.

[image: K5]

For $J\not\simeq G$ I took $K^3$, which is 3-connected and not isomorphic to $K^5$ since they do not have the same number of vertex. Then for $TJ$, I took the graph in red with blue dots in the second picture:

[image: TJ]

Do you agree with me?